# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to run a React native app with this command

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appId com.ursafe_staging
```

But getting this wrong environment path error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installStagingDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Here is my environment path looks like

[image]

and this one

[image]

Still getting the error when I run the command.

Comment: Check if that folder exists on your machine.

Comment: it does exist. I did the java --version.

Comment: @Auvee that doesn't prove the directory exists. It only proves you have a `java.exe` executable in your path

Comment: `java --version` tells you that the `java` command exists somewhere, but it doesn't tell you where. You need to check that the folder exists.

Comment: So how can I check or what should I check?

Comment: Also, since you have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the list you don't need to also include the full path to the jdk's \bin directory that you have listed above it (nor the full path to the jre), as that's redundant.

Comment: No but I am trying to figure it out @Woodchuck

Comment: What do you get if you run this?: where java

Comment: hit windows+R, then enter that path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin). Does it open a folder?

Comment: What is the output of `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` shouldn’t point to the `bin` directory. It should point to the JDK installation path.

It should be: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202`, also you don't need JRE if you already have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux